# Twitter app sends incorrect Activity result after successfully creating a tweet

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric, tweets

I'm composing a Tweet in my app and then launching Twitter app to create that Tweet on user's profile. Following is the code for composing the Tweet and launching of Twitter app

```
TweetComposer.Builder builder = new TweetComposer.Builder(this).text(tweetText);
Intent intent = builder.createIntent();
startActivityForResult(intent, TWEET_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Then I read whether the Tweet was successully created or not through following code:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode = TWEET_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        //do some operation
    }
}
```

The problem is that I get `resultCode = RESULT_CANCELED` in `onActivityResult` instead of `RESULT_OK` despite the Tweet successfully created in Twitter app and appearing on user's timeline and hence the question **Why am I getting RESULT CANCELED instead of RESULT_OK?** I have tried finding the cause of error by checking the `data` object in `onActivityResult` but it is null as well. Is there any other way of finding more about why the app is sending `RESULT_CANCELED`?

Also, I'm not handling user login in my app and let Twitter app to handle that for me. Following is the setup code for Fabric:

```
TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig), new TweetComposer());
```

Version of Twitter SDK: *2.3.2*

Version of Twitter App: *6.48.0*

Comment: I have that issue too. Any news on that?